# Handling Click Events in XAML [UWP]

Tags: xaml, uwp, event-handling

I've got a Panel in my project that is collapsed on the click event of a button, as well as on the Checked event of a radio button.

Currently, I am handling this easily in the code behind.

```
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
    myPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
    myPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

But I am told to do it now in **XAML only** (probably using states in STYLE or such).
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Use XamlBehaviors(https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/ChangePropertyAction).

```
 <Button x:Name="OkButton" Content="OK">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=OkButton}">
                    <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myPanel}" PropertyName="Visibility " Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
```

You can use the same with reference of radioButton too.